# Checkstyle Error in Eclipse - Could not instantiate Tab character

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

Got this error today while trying to build a project with checkstyle. This works for other people in my office but I would rather not reinstall Eclipse yet again. Any idea what this error actually means?

```
Errors occurred during the build.
 Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'myproject'.
  cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate TabCharacter
  cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate TabCharacter
 cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate TabCharacter
 cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate TabCharacter
```

I'm gathering that it has something to do with the tab character but not much else.

UPDATE: Version of Eclipse is 3.5, Checkstyle is 5.0.0.200906281855-final.

(Java is jdk 1.6.0_10)

Comment: "Checkstyle is 5.0.0" means TabCharacter is no longer available: you need to update your Checkstyle configuration file, and double-check what version of Checkstyle the "other people" are using.

Comment: What update to the file exactly is required?

Comment: According to this: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html it seems like the TabCharacter check is now called FileTabCharacter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CASTOR-2756), Checkstyle Plugin version 5.0.0.200906281855:

> [Release notes of Checkstyle 5](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html) state that some of the modules and checks we are using are not backwards compatible.
>   E.g. the **module `TabCharacter` does not occur in v5 any more** (was **replaced by `FileTabCharacter`**), hence can't work.
>   The check `FileLength` does not require a syntax tree, hence is not any longer under parent `TreeWalker`.

That means your issue could be with an automatic update of the Checkstyle plugin in your eclipse configuration.

Comment: Found the problem and it was indeed this. Apparently I'm a version of checkstyle ahead of others. Modified checkstyle.xml to fit 5.0.0, thanks for the help.

Comment: I am a "future" reader and I stil have the problem. I have hundreds of [ERROR] MyClass.java[808:1] (whitespace) FileTabCharacter: Line contains a tab character. I have   Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse 1.0.0.201503101518 com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.feature.group :     Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in 6.11.1.201510102004 net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/     So what I have to do?

Comment: @Aerox 6 years later, I would advise to ask a new question: I don't have those settings available right now.

Comment: Sorry, but I added a comment to reply at @Ewoks that use the sentence "Hint for future readers" posted this year.

Comment: @Aerox OK, I didn't get it at first.

Answer (score -1):

"Same" problem will occur, if you use a checkstyle configuration with self defined cs plugin classes and your plugin.jar is not in your eclipse/plugin path.

So in this case error will just say: *Hey dude: can't find your classes, please give it to me ;)*

Comment: I don't believe that the classes I'm referring to in the question are self defined.

Comment: If question one fixed your problem it's ok for your case, but i thought there might be others running into the same trap as myself and would be glad to see a second possible fix ;) Whether or not the classes are exact, most people will find this "issue" by searching for some parts of the error message too.

Comment: In that case I suggest you make a new question about that issue and then answer your own question, that way it's much more likely that someone will find correct the question and the correct answer. Especially since your problem will likely produce a different error message and have a completely different reason.